# Reading 'ATRX' file in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to read ".atrx" file in R? 
I have been trying to find a function to read this data type but I can not find any.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: More information is needed. What kind of file is this? What have you tried? Please edit accordingly, but also, be aware that requests for recommendations in most cases are a poor fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That file extension does not occur [in this extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions) and Google returns no useful results. Are you sure that it is a file type, not another kind of file (text maybe?) with a misleading extension.